# NodeJS JSON to SQL and SQL to JSON Libraries?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, node.js

So basically I will be getting a feed of a few huge JSON files. I want to convert them into SQL and store them into a MySQL database.

The catch here is that later on I will be needing to get the SQL files from the database and convert them into JSON objects.

https://sqlizer.io/#/ Something like this, where it converts JSON to SQL but vice versa as well.

So I was wondering if there are any NodeJS modules/libraries that have this type of capability.

Thank you.

Comment: Storing the data in a ```JSON``` field not an option?

Comment: See answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33797867/convert-sql-object-to-valid-json-string-in-node-js-azure it seems that an SQL query result is already JSON.

Comment: @Wainage is it bad to store a huge JSON object into one field? Like i can store it as a text but is that bad?

Comment: One large blob yes. But what's the data's shape? Is it an array/hashmap? You could break it up. Even add ```real sql```™ fields to improve queries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where is the problem. With most sql libraries in node, when doing queries in sql, you are getting json back or at least you are getting data that you can convert to JSON with `JSON.stringify`.

Let say we are doing it with knex and Postgres:

```
const db = require('knex')({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
        host : '127.0.0.1',
        user : 'your_database_user',
        password : 'your_database_password',
        database : 'myapp_test'
    }
});

/*
    Let assume the content of the json files is this way:
    [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "last_name": "bar"
        },
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "last_name": "bar"
        }
    ];

    Schema of table should be (
       name TEXT NOT NULL,
       last_name TEXT NOT NULL
    )
*/
// these are the files
const myFilesToRead = ['./file1.json', './file2.json'];

// we are looping through myFilesToRead
// reading the files
// running queries for each object
Promise.all(
    myFilesToRead.map((file) => {
        // yes you can require json files :)
        const fContent = require(file);
        return Promise.all(fContent.map((obj) => {
            // knex is a query builder, it will convert the code below to an SQL statement
            return db('table_name')
            .insert(obj)
            .returning('*')
            .then((result) => {
                console.log('inserted', result);
                return result;
            });
        }));
    })
)
.then((result) => {
    // let's now get these objects back
    return db('table_name')
    .select('*');
})
.then((result) => {
     // that's it
     console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

If you want to read about knex, here is the doc: 
http://knexjs.org/